# Azure DSC - Execute PS Script

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I was not able to find any examples on how to execute my powershell script after it was downloaded and unzip on the targeted node.

I used DSC xRemoteFile to download the package then Archive to unzip my msi and powershell script.

There is a DSC Script resource I can use to Invoke my powershell script, can any of you provide any examples for me to start off? My PS script and MSI is located under C:\Installations.

Example:

```
Script install
{
    GetScript = {
    }
    SetScript = {
    }
    TestScript = {
    }
}
```

Comment: hey mate, consider accepting this answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use script extension for that, it will download the file and execute it.

and in your case you just write the powershell code to execute a script:

```
. .\script.ps1
```

you just need to put in proper path

Comment: I have similar issue. I need to use dsc to download a powershell script and execute its contents. Could you point me to the documentation on "script extension" (instead of xRemoteFile)?

Comment: sure, here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue and this is how our team went about the problem:

```
xRemoteFile DownloadHelloWorldScript
{
    DestinationPath = "c:\Temp\Hello-World.ps1"
    Uri = "https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/public/Temp/Hello-World.ps1"
    MatchSource = $false
}

Script RunHelloWorldScript
{
    SetScript = { . "c:\Temp\Hello-World.ps1" }
    TestScript = { $false } 
    GetScript = { @{ Result = (Get-Content "c:\Temp\Hello-World.ps1") } }
    DependsOn = "[xRemoteFile]DownloadHelloWorldScript"
}
```

When I had `TestScript = { Test-Path "c:\Temp\Hello-World.ps1" }` instead of `{ $false }`, DSC would see that the file had be downloaded and skip running the script. I think I will end up replacing this with some things to check that will verify the script previously ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Configuration Deploy
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
    Import-Dscresource -ModuleName 'PowerShellModule' 
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'Az.Storage'

    Node 'localhost'
    {
       
    # SCRIPT RESOURCE TO DOWNLOAD FILE FROM STORAGE ACCOUNT
        Script DownloadFile{
         GetScript = {""}
         SetScript = {

            $staccname = "strdsctest234r"
            $dest = "C:\Temp"
            $SasToken= "sp=r3D"

            $Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $staccname -SasToken $SasToken
            $Context | Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "test"
            $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "test"  -Context $Context

            # Download each blob from container into destination directory
            $blobs | Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Destination $dest -Force
         }
         TestScript = {$false}
      }}}
```

```
#Deploy -OutputPath C:\Temp\Deploy
#Start-DscConfiguration -path C:\Temp\Deploy -wait -Verbose -Force
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?